# A Quotient Representation of Singular Values of Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, singular-values

The question goes as:

> Let $\sigma_1(A) \geq \sigma_2(A) \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_r(A)$ be all (non-zero) singular values of an order $n$ real matrix $A$. Prove:
> \begin{align*}
> \sigma_k(A) = \sup_{\substack{X \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}\\ X \neq 0}}\frac{\sigma_k(XA)}{\sigma_1(X)}, \quad
> \sigma_{n + 1 - k}(A) = \inf_{\substack{X \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n} \\ X \neq 0}}\frac{\sigma_1(XA)}{\sigma_k(X)},
> \quad \forall k = 1, 2, \ldots, r. 
> \end{align*}

Take the first equality as example, by the definition of singular values and the [representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029358/a-variant-of-min-max-theorem/4029751#4029751) of eigenvalues, I am able tho show that
$\sigma_k(A) \leq \sup_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}}\frac{\sigma_k(XA)}{\sigma_1(X)}$. It seems difficult to obtain the reverse direction. In particular, I don't know how to use the condition that $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Taking into account that the singular values of $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$, the min-max theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) should help.

Comment: @amsmath I tried this way from the very beginning but didn't reach the destination.

Comment: $$
\left(\sup_{X\in\mathbb R^{1\times n}}\frac{\sigma_1(XA)}{\sigma_1(X)}\right)^2 = \sup_{X\in\mathbb R^{1\times n}}\frac{\lambda_1(XAA^*X^*)}{\lambda_1(XX^*)} = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R^{n}}\frac{x^*AA^*x}{x^*x} = \lambda_1(AA^*) = \sigma_1(A)^2.
$$

Comment: how about the general $k > 1$ case?

Comment: Yes, how about that?

Comment: Page 394 in Matrix Computations by Golub and van Loan, third edition, proves the min-max theorem.

Comment: @Jap88 This is not min-max theorem about eigenvalues -- It's some statements about singular values. And as you might have read the former comments, it is not that easy.

Comment: the first line indicates $A$ has $r$ singular values, but $A$ is $n\times n$ so what is the relationship between $r$ and $n$?

Comment: $r$ is the rank of $A$.

Comment: ok.  So $A$ has $n-r$ singular values equal to zero and $\sigma_1(A) \geq \sigma_2(A) \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_r(A)$ does *not* list *all* singular values of $A$ as the first quoted line says.

Comment: @zhanxiong sure min-max is about eigenvalues but in the same book, page 449, they describe how you link this to SVD by applying the theorem to $A^T A$. Many SVD proofs work that way.

Comment: @user8675309 Some author only considers positive square root of $A^TA$ as *singular values*. In this sense $A$ has $r$ singular values. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Jap88 If you can work out the details, please post a complete answer, I will appreciate that. As amsmath tried, the conversion you mentioned is only obvious when $=1$, other cases are much harder than just computing $\lambda_k(A^TA)$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong The inequality which you haven't proven is actually the easy one, in that it holds for all $X,A$ not just $A$ real symmetric. Note that$$A^*X^*XA \le A^*\Vert X^* X\Vert A = \Vert X \Vert^2 A^* A = \sigma_1(X)^2 A^*A.$$ Consequently, $\sigma_k(XA) \le \sigma_1(X) \sigma_k(A)$ for all $k$.

Comment: @J.Loreaux Excellent point! If you can write this idea to  an answer, I can award you the bounty points!

Comment: Can you name the book that uses the convention that $\sigma =0$ is not a singular value?  I've never seen it and all kinds of results break if you use it.  E.g. you can't even sensibly talk about majorization of singular values if you use that convention.

Comment: @user8675309 In a somewhat old Chinese textbook (from which this exercise comes). I agree that it's much more conventional to just allow singular values to be $0$ for many purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\diag}{\mathrm{diag}}$

I will expand @J.Loreaux excellent comment to a more detailed answer for future references. Also, I will take @user8675309's suggestion to allow the singular values to be zero.

For any $1 \leq k \leq r$ and $X \in \real^{k \times n}$, suppose
$$X^TX = O\diag(\sigma_1^2(X), \ldots, \sigma_n^2(X))O^T.$$
is the spectral decomposition of $X^TX$, where $O$ is an order $n$ orthogonal matrix. Recall the notation: for two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, $A - B \geq 0$ means the matrix $A - B$ is positive semi-definite. It then follows that

\begin{align*}
  & \Delta_k := \sigma_1^2(X)A^TA - (XA)^T(XA) = \sigma_1^2(X)A^TA - A^TX^TXA  \\
= & A^T(\sigma_1^2(X)I_{(n)} - X^TX)A = A^TO\diag(0, \sigma_1^2(X) - \sigma_2^2(X), \ldots, \sigma_1^2(X) - \sigma_n^2(X))O^TA \geq 0. 
\end{align*}

Together with $A^TX^TXA \geq 0$, by Courant-Fischer Theorem (see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622747/are-the-eigenvalues-of-the-sum-of-two-positive-definite-matrices-increased)), we then have for every $1 \leq k \leq r$:
\begin{align*}
\lambda_k(\sigma_1^2(X)A^TA) = \lambda_k(A^TX^TXA + \Delta_k) \geq 
\lambda_k(A^TX^TXA),
\end{align*}
which implies
\begin{align*}
\sigma_1(X)\sigma_k(A) \geq \sigma_k(XA).
\end{align*}
This shows
\begin{align*}
\sigma_k(A) \geq \sup_{\substack{X \in \real^{k \times n} \\ X \neq 0}}\frac{\sigma_k(XA)}{\sigma_1(X)}.
\end{align*}
The proof to the other inequality is analogous.